# How do I automate adding all entries in `/etc/hosts` to `~/.ssh/config` file?

Tags: ssh, hosts

Is there a way to convert the format of an /etc/hosts file with

```
"hostaddress" "hostname"
```

into a .ssh/config file with

```
Host myhostname
    Hostname hostaddress
```

I have a large number of hosts and would like to avoid manually adding it all to config

Comment: Don't you mean `Host "hostname"` because you don't have `myhostname` in your `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: I do yes my bad, I tried your awk command but it returned it as

Hostname "hostaddress"
Host "hostname" with the address above the corresponding name rather than below

Comment: Swapped the order around and it worked, thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could use `awk`:

```
awk '{print "Host " $1 "\nHostname " $2}' /etc/hosts
```

Comment: That's a good approach - might want to preface it with a match rule that skips comments and blank lines e.g. `!(/^[[:space:]]*#/ || /^$/)`

Comment: This worked great with a small edit so it read as awk '{print "Hostname " $2 "\nHost " $1 }' /etc/hosts, so that the IP printed under the hostname, question answered thanks a lot